# Pass array from React client to MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have a get route on my server-side that responds with two random records from MongoDB. I currently have a couple records hard-wired as excluded records that will never be returned to the client.

```
app.get("/api/matchups/:excludedrecords", (req, res) => {
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  Restaurant.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: { $nin: [ObjectId("5b6b5188ed2749054c277f95"), ObjectId("50mb5fie7v2749054c277f36")] }
      }
    },
    { $sample: { size: 2 } }
  ]).
```

This works, but I don't want to hard-wire the excluded records, I want to dynamically pass the ObjectIds from the client side. I want the user to be able to exclude multiple records from the random query. I have an action creator that pushes the ObjectId the user wishes to exclude through a reducer so that it becomes part of the store, and the store is an array that includes all the ObjectIds of the records the user wishes to exclude. Here's my action that fetches the random records, taking the excluded records from the store as an argument:

```
export function fetchRecords(excludedrecords) {
  const excludedarray = JSON.stringify(excludedrecords); // Don't currently have this, but feel like I need to.
  const request = 
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/matchups/${excludedarray}`);

  return {
    type: "FETCH_MATCHUP_DATA",
    payload: request
  };
}
```

I have the sense I need to stringify the array on the client side and parse it on the server side, but I'm not sure how. I've started something like:

```
 app.get("/api/matchups/:excludedrecords", (req, res) => {
  const excludedRecords = JSON.parse(req.params.excludedrecords);
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  Restaurant.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: { $nin: [excludedRecords] } // 
      }
    },
```

But how do I get ObjectId() to wrap around each record number that is passed in params? I've tried inserting the number on the client side into a template string, like `ObjectId('${excludedrecord}')`, which results in me passing an array that looks like what I want, but when it gets stringified and parsed it doesn't quite work out.

Sorry if this question is a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should pass the array of string as a body of the http request and not as a part of the url. You do not pass an array parameter as part of the url or in the query string.

Second, you must transcode the to $nin: [ObjectId(excludedRecord1), ObjectId(excludedRecord2)]

at the server side.

Hope it helps!